# How to do a Read instance for a simple custom format of data

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use a short and easy to read format to show and read my data, and I would like that it could be used from the Haskell interpreter, in order to write hand or copy-paste inputs while I try new functions.

My data is a list of Int numbers, each one with an boolean property, that I associate with `+` and `-`, being the first one the default, so it doesn't need explicit representation (as with usual sign). I would like to represent the `-` after the number, like in this example:

```
[2, 5-, 4, 0-, 1, 6-, 2-]
```

Note that I can not use the usual sign because I need to be able of assigning `-` to `0`, so that `0-` is different than `0` (also, may be in the future I will need to use negative numbers, like in `[-4-, -2]`).

I did the easy part, which is to define the data type for the terms of the list and implement the `show` function.

```
data Term = T Int Bool deriving (Eq)

instance Show Term where
    show (T v True)   = show v
    show (T v False)  = show v ++ "-"
```

What I don't know is how to do the corresponding `read` function, or whether I cannot use the `-` sign, because it is a sign of the Haskell language. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
instance Read Term where
  readsPrec n s = do
    (i,rest) <- readsPrec (n+1) s       -- read `i :: Int`
    return $ case rest of               -- look at the rest of the string
      ('-':rest') -> (T i False, rest') -- if it starts with '-'...
      rest' -> (T i True, rest')        -- if it doesn't...
```

`Read` in Haskell follows closely the idea that a parser can be represented by the type `String -> [(a, String)]` (this type is given the type synonym [`ReadS`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#t:ReadS). To familiarize yourself with this idea of parsing, I recommend the reading the following [functional pearl on monadic parsing](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/pearl.pdf).

Then, from GHCi:

```
ghci> read "[2, 5-, 4, 0-, 1, 6-, 2-]" :: [Term]
[2,5-,4,0-,1,6-,2-]
```

Comment: @enrique Oops! Try it now. :)

Comment: It was hard for me to understand this: `case rest of ('-':rest) ...`, until I noticed that the first `rest` is not the same than second `rest`. So I suggest using different name, I renamed the second to `r` in the 4 places used. Otherwise, it is a great solution, simple and clean, with which I understood Read, at last, better than the ubiquitous, but more difficult for the novel, example of Tree. Thanks!

Comment: I guess that's a good point about `rest` - let me change the second one to `rest'`. And you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I like very much the answer of Alec, which I accepted. But after reading, thinking and trying, I reached another quite simple solution, that I would like to share here.

It uses `reads` instead of `readsPrec` because the `Term` constructor is not infix, so we don't need to manage precedence, and it is not monadic.

```
instance Read Term where
  readsPrec _ s = 
    [(T v False, rest)  | (v, '-' : rest) <- reads s] ++ 
    [(T v True , rest)  | (v,       rest) <- reads s]
```

The symmetry with the corresponding `Show` instance is notable:

```
instance Show Term where
  show (T v True)   = show v
  show (T v False)  = show v ++ "-"
```